# Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios7.1

I am getting this error in collection view.
I have implemented this method and i am returning a footer for last section.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == LAST_SECTION_INDEX) 
    {
        return CGSizeMake(self.view.width, 50);
    }

    return CGSizeZero;
}
```

and in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method i have implemented like this `CollectionViewFooter` is a subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` class

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewFooter *footer = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:FooterIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      return footer;
}
```

when collection view reloads it is crashing and giving me this error.

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:]

I am stuck here. Can anyone please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: replace `kind` with `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter` in `dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind`